# Grommet installation and configuration in windows 7

Tags: node.js, user-interface, npm, grommet

When I try to install Grommet in windows 7 using command prompt, it gives the errors as "Cannot find Module". I have been following this tutorial to set up the environment...http://www.grommet.io/docs/hpe/develop/get-started.....When I run gulp dev, it gives the error as  "Cannot find Module"..I even tried npm uninstall and then npm install but it doesn't work either. 
**"node version":"4.4.0","npm version":"2.14.20".**
Also, I am not behind a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem with the node js and npm version. Required version is mentioned in the docs. If even that doesn't work, try installing in a different folder, which worked in my case.